# Is there a sample example where AngularJS authentication is setup with Azure AD and Spring boot

Tags: angularjs, spring-boot, azure, azure-active-directory

We have two separate apps for both front-end written in AngularJS (from 5 years ago) and back-end in Spring boot which are deployed separately

Is there a way of using Azure AD authentication with AngularJS front-end and Spring-boot back-end?

Comment: check this and see if this helps https://ordina-jworks.github.io/security/2020/08/18/Securing-Applications-Azure-AD.html

Answer (score 0):

> Is there a way of using Azure AD authentication with AngularJS
> front-end and Spring-boot back-end?

To use Azure AD authentication with AngularJS (Front-end) and spring-boot ( back end) ,Here is the  [sample/Example](https://ordina-jworks.github.io/security/2020/08/18/Securing-Applications-Azure-AD.html) .

Also , You can grant Authentication using  [Microsoft identity platform and OAuth 2.0 authorization code flow](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/active-directory/develop/v2-oauth2-auth-code-flow) .

**Reference:**

. [Angular MSAL Login example| GitHub](https://github.com/tamani-coding/angular-msal-login-example)

. [Authentication for application with Azure AD](https://medium.com/@raviraj199602/azure-active-directory-authentication-for-application-with-azure-ad-a9e5fb513b40)

Comment: This is Angular 2+, however we are trying to see if it works using plain javascript